# How to get all related items like "with" in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm sorry, I don't even know how to ask for what I need...

User:

```
id
```

MyItem:

```
id
item_id
user_id
```

Item:

```
id
```

How to get `$user->items()`?

I guess `hasManyThrough()` won't help here.

Thank your very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined your relationship and have `items` relation in your `User` model, you can get them using:

```
foreach ($user->items as $item) {
   echo $item->id;
}
```

As it's many to many relationship, in class `User` you need to define your relationship this way:

```
public function items() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Item');
}
```

and in `Item` class this way:

```
public function users() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

And your pivot_table should have here name `item_user`. If it's not, pass your table name as 2nd argument to `belongsToMany` method

Comment: I don't have a relationship defined. That's the problem. I don't know how to define it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want exactly but 
i think you need  user relative  more  information 
if you want user relative in formation 
so please  try this 
you  get all information about user

```
$users = User::all();
```